# Angular not fetching data from factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi i have the following plunker using a factory:  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VkTGHiXzsqWM82OBMxqS?p=preview)

When we click the button next to `my academic programs`, it gives a panel with the `applied science` and `academic` buttons. When we click on one of the buttons, it gives a list of some programs. When we click on one of those programs, it brings another panel which should contain the children of those programs.

I defined these children in a factory(`services.js`). But it is not bringing those elements from the json file. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. your path to your `data.json` (its currently `data.js`) file is wrong.
2. the json in the file is incorrect.  You need to wrap all properies with `''`.
3. Your path to bootstrap is wrong so its crashing on `$().tooltip()`

You had not even plugged up the service call.  I added  `jsonService` as a dependancy.  `JsonService` as an injectable:

```
var app = angular.module('StudentProgram', ['ui.bootstrap', 'jsonService']);

    app.controller('mycontroller', function(JsonService, $scope, $modal, $log) {
```

---

Then i added to your scope a call to get the data

```
JsonService.query(function(data){
    $scope.degreecategories  = data;
console.log(data);
});
```

**Working** [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4i3EWKt8n45WQk5hxaaQ?p=preview) .  Please next time point more work into your question... you are lucky I am *bored*.